# Add Child Object in Session Laravel

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5, session-variables

I'm using Laravel 5.4.

I'm creating a very basic store app. Whereby, you can select products, add them to a basket, and either continue shopping or checkout.

I have a stage called "Order Setup" where logged in users define certain parameters, this then gets stored into session with the object `order`. e.g.:

```
$order = new Order();
  $order->company_id = $data['company_id'];
  $order->customer_id = $data['customer_id'];
  $order->delivery_address_id = $data['delivery_address_id'];
  $order->total_cost = 0.0;
  $order->limit_remaining = $limitRemaining;
  $order->delivery_cost = $customer->delivery_cost;
  $order->minShipDate = $customer->minDespatchDate();
   $order->deliveryOptions = DeliveryOptions::where('deleted', 0)->pluck('name', 'id');

$request->session()->put('order', $order);
```

At a later point, when a user adds an item to the "order" object above, i want to create a child object of the parent "order" above. e.g. of building the object below, but what's the best way to append this in session, whilst maintaining a relationship?

```
$orderDetail = new OrderDetail();
    $orderDetail->stock_code = $orderItem['stock_code'];
    $orderDetail->quantity = floatval($orderItem['quantity']);
    $orderDetail->cost = floatval($productSetup->price);
    $orderDetail->line_price = $productSetup->price * $orderItem['quantity'];
```

Comment: You are keeping the $order and $orderDetail variables separated. Why won't store them in separated session variables as well?

Comment: @JoséA.Zapata I've only done that because they happen at different events/times, i want them to be relational, an $order has many $orderDetails, but i'm unsure how to form that relationship in session. It will be stored in the database on order place.

Comment: My point is that you don't actually need an explicit relationship in the session, just as you don't need an explicit relationship between the `$order` and `$orderDetail` variables.

Comment: In addition to @JoséA.Zapata I'd go further and just store the order identifier in the session. Any information about the order can be retrieved later using the identifier with a simple query. If you need to join more tables to the query you can use ```with``` to include them in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JoséA.Zapata said in the comment you don't need explicit relationship you just create another session variable for $orderDetail and store an array of order details in it. You will also need an extra session variable to store index of the object in array.

```
$orderDetailsArray= array();
 $index=0;
//Now store the $orderDetail object in the array.
$orderDetailsArray[index]=$orderDetail; //order detailDetail object which you have created

//Initiliaze Sessions for orderdetails and index
Session::put('orderDetails',$orderDetailsArray);
Session::put('index',$index);
```

Now when you store next orderDetail object, first you have to retrieve the orderDetails session and put new orderdetail in it.

```
//increment the old index
$newIndex=Session::get('index');
$newIndex++;
$orderDetailsArray=Session::get('orderDetails');

$orderDetailsArray[$newIndex]=$newOrderDetailObject;
```

I hope this method will help to achieve what you want.